# SQL Where NOT IN returns blank

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the rows where id are not in a list.
I have email with scores with several email for each score. I know how to get the max score for each email then I want to delete other rows. I try to delete all rows that are not in the list of max score but it does not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mkgaction AS a
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM
                     (SELECT * 
                      FROM mkgaction AS b 
                      ORDER BY `score` DESC) x
                 GROUP BY `score`)
```

The select id returns me the right list but the all request returns me no line...

Do you know why?

Comment: Your query is malformed . . . you have `select *` with `group by`.  Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation, and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: It looks like the sub select will return every id in the table because there’s no WHERE clause in it. If this is there case, no ids are not in that list, therefore it won’t return any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably -- if your query works at all -- you are using MySQL.  The syntax in that database is:

```
delete ma
    from mkgaction ma join
         (select ma2.email, max(ma2.score) as max_score
          from mkgaction ma2
          group by ma2.email
         ) ma2
         on ma.email = ma2.email and ma.score < ma2.max_score;
```

Comment: Oh my. It works, it does not look like my initial request, so I will need little time to understand it but thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Chènevis . . . This is more based on your description of the problem than your query.